# error the input data is not complete block

Tags: c#, aes

[image]

I make a chat application and I use AES algorithm. But I see this error " the input data is not complete block".

This is my code:

```
        public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, string key, string mode)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            if (mode == "ECB") aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            else if (mode == "CBC") aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            else if (mode == "CFB") aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

            aesAlg.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            aesAlg.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 16));

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

The error is in line: plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
I don't know why.

Help me, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Picture is not really helpful. Please remove the image and try to correctly catch the exception into a console or a log file. Then provide the actual error text in your question.

Comment: I have no idea about the rest of your code, but if you're using sockets, remember that one call to `Read()` doesn't necessarily return a whole "message", or even a single message. What might be two messages sent client-side might arrive in one read, or in three reads, etc.